# Firebase Custom Token with JWTS

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am new to Firebase and want to authenticate firebase with a custom token on android.
I have Implemented Jwts for generating the custom tokens. Below is the code for it.

```
serializer=new Serializer<Map<String, ?>>() {
        @Override
        public byte[] serialize(Map<String, ?> stringMap) throws SerializationException {
            return new byte[0];
        }
    };
    resolver=new CompressionCodec() {
        @Override
        public String getAlgorithmName() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] compress(byte[] payload) throws CompressionException {
            return new byte[0];
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] decompress(byte[] compressed) throws CompressionException {
            return new byte[0];
        }
    };

    deserializer=new Deserializer<Map<String, ?>>() {
        @Override
        public Map<String, ?> deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws DeserializationException {
            return null;
        }
    };


    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date=new Date();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    Calendar calendar1=calendar;
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND,3550);//expiration time =iat time + 3550 seconds 
    //Header Map
    Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<>();
    map.put("alg", "HS256");
    map.put("typ", "JWT");
    //Claim map
    Map<String ,Object> map1=new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("uid",23423423);
    map1.put("sub","firebase@PROJECT-ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com");
    map1.put("iss","firebase@PROJECT-ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com");map1.put("aud","https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit");
    map1.put("iat",calendar1.getTime().getTime());
    map1.put("exp",calendar.getTime().getTime());


     Key key= Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256);
    String customToken=Jwts.builder().setHeaderParams(map).setIssuedAt(calendar1.getTime())
            .setExpiration(calendar.getTime())
            .setClaims(map1)
            .serializeToJsonWith(serializer)
            .compressWith(resolver)
            .signWith(key).compact();
    MainActivity.instance_main.showToast(customToken);




 final FirebaseAuth mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuth.signInWithCustomToken(customToken).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
   if(task.isSuccessful())
   {
       // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
       Log.d("FIREBASE_LOGIN_STATUS", "signInWithCustomToken:success");
       FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
       MainActivity.instance_main.showToast("LOGGEDIN_FIREBASE : "+user.toString());
   }
   else
   {
       Log.w("FIREBASE_LOGIN_STATUS", "signInWithCustomToken:failure", task.getException());
       MainActivity.instance_main.showToast("LOGGEDIN_FIREBASE : FAILED");
       MainActivity.instance_main.showToast(task.getException().getMessage());
   }
   // updateUI(user);
}
```

});

PROJECT-ID is the id of the project.
But Firebase login is getting failed with the following exception - The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation.[invalid assertion format, missing segment.]
I tried searching for the solution online but no luck. Please help me resolve this issue. And please ignore any mistakes, not directly related to this problem.

Comment: Are you trying to generate a custom token from within the Android app that then also uses that token? That is highly insecure, as allows anyone to generate any token they want and sign with that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I tried generating custome token from jwt.io but generated token from there also does not work.Any suggestion on how to generate 3rd party custom token.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen and i am also not sure what will be iat and exp for 3rd party generated custom token.As token will be valid for only 1 hour(3600 seconds).do i have to generate it again and again.

Comment: Generating a custom token for a project requires that you specify the administrative credentials/private key for that project, which should only ever be done in a trusted environment. See this page for a list of options on how to safely generate such a token: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens